# Неправильно срабатывает применение Drawable

Tags: android, android-drawable

Столкнулся с ошибкой при отображении `Drawable` примененного на кнопки.
Есть 2 `linearLayout` по 2 `Button`.
В каждой группе может выбираться только одна кнопка. На выбранной кнопке применяю `Drawable btnBackgroundOn`. На невыбранную - соответствующе применяю `Drawable btnBackgroundOff`.

**Проблема:** Если `Activity` теряет фокус, потом восстановить - то заливка кнопок становится только частичной.

При поиске причины заметил следующее:
1) Ширина залитого пространства на кнопках становится равной ширине одной из выбранных кнопок.
2) Кнопки одной группы вроде как не влияют на заливку друг-друга.
3) После восстановления не замечал проблем если кнопки второй группы не трогать.

**До потери фокуса:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**После восстановления фокуса:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Минимальный код в котором сохраняется ошибка:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btn1a, btn1b, btn2a, btn2b;

    @BindViews({R.id.btn_1_a, R.id.btn_1_b})
    List<Button> listFirst;
    @BindViews({R.id.btn_2_a, R.id.btn_2_b})
    List<Button> listSecond;

    @BindDrawable(R.drawable.draw_color_on)
    Drawable btnBackgroundOn;
    @BindDrawable(R.drawable.draw_color_off)
    Drawable btnBackgroundOff;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        btn1a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1_a);
        btn1b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1_b);
        btn2a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2_a);
        btn2b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2_b);

        btn1a.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn1b.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2a.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void changeColorButton(List listBtn, Button curBtn) {

        for (int i = 0; i < listBtn.size(); i++) {

            if (listBtn.get(i) != curBtn) {
                ((Button) listBtn.get(i)).setBackground(btnBackgroundOff);

            } else {
                curBtn.setBackground(btnBackgroundOn);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

            //Block 1
            case R.id.btn_1_a:
                changeColorButton(listFirst, btn1a);
                break;
            case R.id.btn_1_b:
                changeColorButton(listFirst, btn1b);
                break;

            //Block 2
            case R.id.btn_2_a:
                changeColorButton(listSecond, btn2a);
                break;
            case R.id.btn_2_b:
                changeColorButton(listSecond, btn2b);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**layout_main:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff5cb"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_1_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/draw_color_off"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="First button text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_1_b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/draw_color_off"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="2-nd txt" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#E0E0E0" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_2_a"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/draw_color_off"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="small" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_2_b"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/draw_color_off"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="Some text" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**draw_color_on.xml:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

**draw_color_off.xml:**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
</shape>
```

Проверял влияет ли библиотека `ButterKnife` - не влияет.
Стиль и манифест без особенностей.

Предполагаю что проблема может решиться если на каждую группу делать свой пакет `Drawable`.

Без `Drawable`не обойдусь, так как приложении которое делаю имеет много групп кнопок, а `Drawable` имеют несколько замудренных слоев `shape`.

Помогите понять где допустил ошибку в применении `Drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать

```
setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(R.drawable.draw_color_on))
```

и

```
setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(R.drawable.draw_color_off))
```

соответсвенно

Comment: Уже в процессе использования добавил отсутствующий в Вашем примере `this` и все заработало. Ваш вопрос отмечаю как Принятый, так как он открыл мне глаза на мою ошибку - я неверно доставал `Drawable`. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вы почти правы по поводу:

> Предполагаю что проблема может решиться если на каждую группу делать свой пакет Drawable.

Да только, вероятнее всего придется делать это для каждого `Button`. Что  точно будет неудобно.
Проще всего как и написал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868135/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-drawable/868207#868207) Александр Соболь, применять к кнопке `Drawable` сразу доставая с ресурсов через `ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, <ВАШ_Drawable>)`.

Тогда Ваш код будет таким:

```
private void changeColorButton(List listBtn, Button curBtn) {

    for (int i = 0; i < listBtn.size(); i++) {

        if (listBtn.get(i) != curBtn) {
            ((Button) listBtn.get(i)).setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.draw_color_off));

        } else {
            curBtn.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.draw_color_on));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за рабочий пример и за комментарии. И все же, уже получил дельный ответ ранее Вашего. Ваш ответ однозначно плюсую )

Comment: Все верно, Вы отметили тот вопрос который Вас изначально натолкнул на нужную мысль.